# How to display icon in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I want to use the icon? or is it the alternative span tag? (No idea what its actually called) Anyways, I want to display a icon in my menu here is my current source code.

```
<li><i class="material-icons left">person</i><%= link_to   signup_path %></li>
```

This is what I currently get 
And here is the html I want it to generate:

[image]

```
<li><a href="signup.html"><i class="material-icons">person/i></a></li>
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an ERB link in Rails that accomplishes the normal HTML code you provided, do this:

```
<%= link_to signup_path do %>
    <i class="material-icons left">person</i>
<% end %>
```

This will generate:

```
<a href="signup.html"><i class="material-icons left">person</i></a>
```

Comment: Or you can just use `<%= link_to(raw('<i class="material-icons left"></i> person')  %>`

Answer (score 0):

Only posting this answer because it is *possible* to do it this way.. definitely not preferred `:)`

```
<%= link_to '<i class="material-icons left">person</i>'.html_safe, signup_path %>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= link_to  signup_path do %>
    <i class="material-icons left"> person </i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That is not the correct way to pass a block into `link_to` -- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to -- When providing a block, the link's name does not get added as the first param

Comment: @WesFoster, you're right.  that's true.. the name is used as the innerHTML.. it wouldn't make sense to specify the text of the link *and* a block as the text